# Probability of specific item being one of three picked from group of six

Tags: probability

I have six items, A through F.

I will be randomly selecting three of these.

What is the probability that item A will be one of the three selected?

Comment: How many $3$-element subsets of $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ are there? How many of them contain $A$?

Comment: What is the chance A does *not* get selected?

Comment: It's been years since I took discrete math and I don't remember the formula for n choose k or how many sub sets it's in.

Comment: The formula for n choose k is $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pick one specific item and some other items from remaining. Then fix the probability of that item as 1.

P = 1 * $\frac{C(5,2)}{C(6,2)}$

= 1 * $\frac{\frac{5!}{2!\times3!}}{\frac{6!}{2!\times4!}}$

= $\frac{10}{15} = \frac{2}{3}$